Face ID no longer works after activating Stolen Device Protection
The Face ID feature on my Apple iPhone 12 Pro no longer works after activating Stolen Device Protection. I can't even reset face ID in security settings either.
According to Apple website:

When Stolen Device Protection is enabled, some features and actions
have additional security requirements when your iPhone is away from
familiar locations such as home or work.

However, I am at home on my home network. So I tracked down some info from Apple about how to fix this. The Apple website also instructs users to:


Go to Settings, then tap Face ID & Passcode.

Enter your device passcode.

Tap Stolen Device Protection, then turn Stolen Device Protection on or
off.



However when I attempt to disable the Stolen Device Protection, the Face ID kicks in and tells me 'Face not recognized'
I attempted to reset my Face ID, but again, the Face ID kicks in and tells me 'Face not recognized'
What can I do to disable Stolen Device Protection and restore the Face ID on my iPhone?
Running iOS 17.5.1 on iPhone 12 Pro

When is your last backup? Why not ask apple support?

@bmike I don't have a backup. I'm asking here for various reasons.

If you had a backup, that would make for an easy answer. I might answer that to help others even if you can’t take advantage of that.
